# VirtualizingStackPanel with cache

Tags: c#, wpf

We have to requirement to virtualize a ListView/ItemsControl with a VirtualizingStackPanel. Although everything works as expected, the Control's ItemTemplate adheres a complex control with a lot of computation during its initialization phase - which has to be done on the UI thread. In other words, scrolling leads to UI freezes - which is fine if it only has to be done once. As we can't use the `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycle"` (due to several other restrictions) we have to try something different.

I thought of a "cached" virtualizingStackPanel which doesn't actually dispose the ItemTemplate's Template, but rather 'freezes' the control. When the user scrolls back to a - previously loaded template - we could simply 'unfreeze' the control.

The 'freeze' can be implemented by overwriting `OnCleanUpVirtualizedItem`, such as:

```
    protected override void OnCleanUpVirtualizedItem(CleanUpVirtualizedItemEventArgs args)
    {
        var stuff = FindChild<HeavyStuff>(args.UIElement);

        if (stuff != null)
        {
            int idx = Children.IndexOf(args.UIElement);

            if (!_buffer.ContainsKey(idx))
                _buffer.Add(idx, args.UIElement);

            stuff.Freeze();
            args.Handled = true;
            args.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnCleanUpVirtualizedItem(args);
        }
    }
```

That works pretty well. The control stays within the VisualTree and it simply 'freezes' and avoids any user-input and the potential resulting workload. However, I couldn't figure out on howto 'unfreeze' the control when it comes back into view. I dug through the [reference-source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/VirtualizingStackPanel.cs) and found the [`BringIndexIntoView`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/VirtualizingStackPanel.cs,6a55051802ab6eb6,references), which could potentially solve my issue like the following:

```
     protected override void BringIndexIntoView(int index)
    {
        if (_buffer.ContainsKey(index))
        {
            FindChild<HeavyStuff>(_buffer[index]).UnFreeze();
        }
        else
        {
            base.BringIndexIntoView(index);
        }
    }
```

However, that method never gets called by the internal VirtualizingStackPanel logic. My second thought was to override the `IItemContainerGenerator`, as the generator does provide the `DependencyObjects` on demand. But again without any luck. One can't inherit the `ItemContainerGenerator`, because it is sealed. Secondly, defining a proxy and overwriting the `ItemContainerGenerator` properties doesn't help either, as the base class doesn't call that VirtualizingStackPanel's ItemContainerGenerator property at all:

```
    public new IItemContainerGenerator ItemContainerGenerator => generator;
```

Is there any way to obtain the information when a control scrolls back into the view, without the VirtualizingStackPanel re-creating an instance?

Addon: I also thought about virtualizing the data-source itself. However, even if we would virtualize the data source, the global user input would lead the controls to perform CPU and UI-thread intensive operations. Hence, it doesn't matter which way we choose, we do have to 'freeze' and 'unfreeze' certain, non-viewport-related controls. In other words, we need UI virtualization nevertheless.

EDIT: "Freeze" and "Unfreeze" does not refer to the .NET object freezing. My poor choice of words may cause that confusion. With "freeze" and "unfreeze" I do refer to some internal logic which subscribes or unsubscribes from various event handlers, such that controls, beeing out of the viewport, don't require to process that input.

Comment: Why don't you cache the outcome of heavy intensive work in VM for each item?

Comment: Bc. the heavy work results in a populated canvas. Even with the values cached, one would still require to re-draw the entire thing. That takes a lot of time on the UI thread.

Comment: So you want caching but the caching aka container recycling provided by the VirtualizingStackPanel is not good? If you have such a special use case than you should implement your own panel. This way you can control the item cache. It also seems like you misunderstood Freezable. It's not about persisting the object's state. It's about unhooking the object from the dependency property engine. You can't unfreeze a Freezable. You must clone it (by calling Freezable.Clone()). You usually would focus on the data models. You must persist or cache the state of the models.

Comment: @BionicCode Freeze and Unfreeze, unfortunately, overlap with pre-existing function. My freeze and unfreeze are actually called different and they have nothing todo with the .NET object freezing.

Comment: I see. Your statement *"I couldn't figure out on howto 'unfreeze' the control when it comes back into view"* made me wonder. So you should know how to unfreeze objects. You just wrote that you don't know. Still, it sounds like you are reinventing the wheel. UI virtualization is already working. You only need to find a way to persist data, which is normally not a problem as long the item's lifetime is controlled. The problem is that the moment you disconnect a UIElement from the tree, it needs to be regenerated. So I don't see how you can improve the UI virtualization algorithm.

Comment: Usually, you only have very few visible items and this is no problem. Which makes me wonder what exactly your containers look like? It seems you should focus on the initialization and implementation of the container templates and optimize the visual tree to improve rendering. First start to throw all the Borders and other unused container elements over board. Replace Grid with StackPanel. Use TextBlock instead of Label. Use OneTime bindings instead of OneWay etc. If you have complex visuals then there usually is a lot to improve.

Comment: The thing already has been optimized to its limits ;) Caching VM stuff skips the heavy CPU bound workloads upon UI initialization, but the canvas still needs to be populated. (Imaging drawing millions of points on a canvas - depending on your VM data) Hence, even if we remember all VM data we still need to re-initialise the control. Thus, my idea is to "freeze" aka remove all listeners from UI-elements out of view. This already works, but I can't figure out of to re-use already initialized controls. (Without a custom VirtualizationStackPanel)

Comment: For what you want it sounds like you don't want the VirtualizingPanel. To clarify the context, VirtualizingPanel helps to reduce the memory footprint by removing or disconnecting containers from the visual tree. This will also increase the rendering performance as only a few number of items (realized) must participate in the layout pass. That's why you get smooth scrolling and fast loading times. You want to throw all this away and keep all containers in memory, and more important, connected to the visual tree. You only want to unhook event handlers.

Comment: If this is what you want, you must extend and use a simple StackPanel. Then track the position of every container to know when they are in and out of the viewport to register/unregister event handlers. That's quite trivial if I understood your goal correctly in the first place. Did I?

Comment: To me, it sounds more reasonable to optimize your container initialization routine. *"a complex control with a lot of computation during its initialization phase - which has to be done on the UI thread. In other words, scrolling leads to UI freezes - which is fine if it only has to be done once."*. You should store the computation result and reuse it to initialize realized containers. You should not throw away virtualization if you expect or allow many items - which you obviously do.

Comment: @BionicCode Yes, you did understand me correctly. The issue with that approach (loading the entire collection simultaneously) leaves the application unresponsive. However, now that I rethink the entire situation (with your suggestions in mind) your original suggestion (data virtualization) in combination with a normal StackPanel might be one possible solution after all. Load 'n' entries, lazy load more uppon scrolling and just keep them in a normal stackpanel.

Comment: Do you know any useful sources on howto tackle data virtualization in such a case? All what I can think of is implementing a custom stackpanel, set the height to some artificial value (COUNT * POSSIBLE HEIGHT), observing the scroll value and append new items to the observable collection.

Comment: I have improved the performance of my answer significantly, especially for a scenario with many items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following example implementation that extends the `StackPanel` to tracks the visibility of its hosted containers (in terms of the parent scroll viewer's viewport).
Simply set the custom `Panel` as `ItemsPanel` to the `ListBox`.
It's important that the parent `ScrollViewer` has the `CanContentScroll` property set to `true` (which is the default for the `ListBox`).

Since `StackPanel` already implements `IScrollInfo`, observing the scroll event and viewport is very straight forward.
Add your actual implementation, to handle the changed containers and/or their hosted models, to the `OnHiddenContainersChanged` method to complete the `Panel`.

```cs
public class ScrollWatcherPanel : StackPanel
{
  public ScrollWatcherPanel()
  {
    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
  }

  private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (!this.ScrollOwner.CanContentScroll)
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll must be enabled.");
    }
    this.ScrollOwner.ScrollChanged += OnScrollChanged;
  }

  protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
  {
    base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);
    HandleAllContainers();
  }

  private void OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e) 
    => HandleContainerVisibilityChanges((int)e.VerticalChange);

  private void HandleAllContainers()
  {
    int containersBeforeViewportStartCount = (int)this.VerticalOffset;
    int containersBeforeViewportEndCount = containersBeforeViewportStartCount + (int)this.ViewportHeight + 1;

    var newHiddenContainers = new List<FrameworkElement>();
    var newVisibleContainers = new List<FrameworkElement>();
    for (int childContainerIndex = 0; childContainerIndex < this.InternalChildren.Count; childContainerIndex++)
    {
      bool isContainerHiddenBeforeViewport = childContainerIndex < containersBeforeViewportStartCount;
      bool isContainerVisibleInViewport = childContainerIndex < containersBeforeViewportEndCount;

      var childContainer = (FrameworkElement)this.InternalChildren[childContainerIndex];
      if (isContainerHiddenBeforeViewport)
      {
        newHiddenContainers.Add(childContainer);
      }
      else if (isContainerVisibleInViewport)
      {
        newVisibleContainers.Add(childContainer);
      }
      else // Container is hidden after viewport
      {
        newHiddenContainers.Add(childContainer);
      }
    }

    OnHiddenContainersChanged(newHiddenContainers, newVisibleContainers);
  }

  private void HandleContainerVisibilityChanges(int verticalChange)
  {
    int containersBeforeViewportStartCount = (int)this.VerticalOffset;
    int containersBeforeViewportEndCount = containersBeforeViewportStartCount + (int)this.ViewportHeight + 1;
    int newHiddenContainerCount = Math.Abs(verticalChange);
    int newVisibleContainerCount = Math.Abs(verticalChange);
    bool isScrollingDown = verticalChange > 0;
    int changeCount = Math.Abs(verticalChange);

    var newHiddenContainers = new List<FrameworkElement>();
    var newVisibleContainers = new List<FrameworkElement>();
    int changesIndex = Math.Max(0, containersBeforeViewportStartCount - changeCount);
    for (int childContainerIndex = changesIndex; childContainerIndex < this.InternalChildren.Count; childContainerIndex++)
    {
      bool isContainerHiddenBeforeViewport = childContainerIndex < containersBeforeViewportStartCount;
      bool isContainerVisibleInViewport = childContainerIndex < containersBeforeViewportEndCount;

      var childContainer = (FrameworkElement)this.InternalChildren[childContainerIndex];
      if (isContainerHiddenBeforeViewport)
      {
        if (isScrollingDown)
        {
          bool isContainerNewHidden = childContainerIndex >= containersBeforeViewportStartCount - changeCount
            && newHiddenContainerCount > 0;
          if (isContainerNewHidden)
          {
            newHiddenContainers.Add(childContainer);
            newHiddenContainerCount--;
          }
        }
      }
      else if (isContainerVisibleInViewport)
      {
        if (isScrollingDown)
        {
          bool isContainerNewVisible = childContainerIndex >= containersBeforeViewportEndCount - changeCount
            && newVisibleContainerCount > 0;
          if (isContainerNewVisible)
          {
            newVisibleContainers.Add(childContainer);
            newVisibleContainerCount--;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          bool isContainerNewVisible = childContainerIndex >= containersBeforeViewportStartCount
            && newVisibleContainerCount > 0;
          if (isContainerNewVisible)
          {
            newVisibleContainers.Add(childContainer);
            newVisibleContainerCount--;
          }
        }
      }
      else // Container is hidden after viewport (on scroll up)
      {
        if (!isScrollingDown)
        {
          bool isContainerNewHidden = childContainerIndex >= containersBeforeViewportEndCount 
            && newHiddenContainerCount > 0;
          if (isContainerNewHidden)
          {
            newHiddenContainers.Add(childContainer);
            newHiddenContainerCount--;
            if (newHiddenContainerCount == 0)
            {
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    OnHiddenContainersChanged(newHiddenContainers, newVisibleContainers);
  }

  protected virtual void OnHiddenContainersChanged(IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> newHiddenContainers, IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> newVisibleContainers)
  {
    // TODO::Handle "hidden"/"visible" item containers, that are just scrolled out of/into the viewport.
    // You can access the DataContext of the containers to get a reference to the underlying data model.
  }
}
```

Comment: I had to tinker with the `verticalChange` value and the `isContainerNewVisible` condition, as several cases were not covered. As an exmaple, if you add only one item to the StackPanel no newVisibleContainer will be raised, as the verticalChange equals 0. I also would suggest to add (like the VirtualizingStackPanel) a CacheLength property to return more results than computed. (Else there might be cases whereas the most bottom control won't load when there are only 1-4px left, which looks unpleasant) Else it works as expected. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Agree, there's enough to improve in order to make it perfect. It was just meant to give you something to work with. It just shows the basic concept. Adding a virtual cache makes perfect sense. In case you are registering event handlers inside the panel, you should maintain a table like a HashSet to keep track of the items. You want to make sure you remove all handlers in a scenario where items are removed from the panel owner.

Comment: Since you don't need any virtualization and you don't modify the layout behavior of the panel, it makes even more sense to extend ListBox instead of StackPanel and move the above code to it. From the ListBox you can get access to the ScrollViewer (using the VisualTreeHelper) and in addition to the OnItemsSourceChanged override to handle the item changes. I personally would move the code to a custom ListBox. The above implementation doesn't even require modifications. But don't forget to disable UI virtualization for the ListBox.

Comment: Yup, that would be fine. But we use ItemsControl/ListView alongside the ListBox, such that `ItemsPanelTemplate` is the way to go, as it can be reused throughout all different controls.